# Coefficients of Gaussian mixture

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution

This is in context of Gaussian mixtures
$$p(\boldsymbol{x}) = \sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k\cal{N}(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu_k},\boldsymbol{\Sigma_k})$$

[Bishop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) mentions on Page-111

> Also, the requirement that $p(\boldsymbol{x})\ge 0$, together with $\cal{N}(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu_k},\boldsymbol{\Sigma_k})\ge$ $0$, implies $\pi_k\ge0$ for all $k$

How do we prove this?

A trivial counter-example that comes is ($k=2$), with a single Gaussian taken twice (i.e., $\boldsymbol{\mu_1}=\boldsymbol{\mu_2}$, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma_1}=\boldsymbol{\Sigma_2}$) and $\pi_1=1.2$, $\pi_2=-0.2$.

Comment: What do you want to prove? That if one of the elements in the sum is negative, the total can be negative?

Comment: As mentioned, I want to prove the cited statement . And I don't know if the claim itself is correct -- the "counter-example" is for the same.

Comment: It's a requirement, what about it you want to prove?

Comment: I want to prove the "implies $\pi_k \ge 0$" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the quote. The requirement follows from the fact that we need $p(\boldsymbol x)$ to be a proper probability distribution (non-negative, that integrates to 1), so we use a convex combination of the mixture components. Moreover, $\pi_k$ weights are interpreted as probabilities, which makes the model have an [intuitive interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/543755/35989).

See also [Intuition for why sum of gaussian RVs is different from gaussian mixture](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/309154/35989)

Comment: I had [earlier edited my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/593279/3) to correct the counter-example.

Comment: I agree to the probabilistic interpretation of $\pi_k$.
As a requirement, it is fine (but the author didn't put it that way).

Comment: @abs regardless of the interpretation, the first part of the answer applies, the result needs to be proper distribution. Maybe the wording was unfortunate, but the author just lists a set of conditions that make it true.

Comment: But is it true that a concave combination necessarily does not give a proper distribution?

Comment: As an aside, the author *imposes* $0\le\pi_k\le1$ on page-431 (9.8). This, with the cited statement in the question, seems confusing.

Comment: @abs he just lists the conditions for the model. If $\pi_k$ are nonnegative and sum to 1, they cannot be higher than 1. Those conditions make it all work together, nothing more, nothing less. It's not a theorem that would be broadly applicable, but a definition of specific model with its assumptions.